# replacing specific position of a string

Tags: java, string, str-replace

I have a fixed length String record, i want to replace the string at a specific position with different string value.

```
String record ="ABCU0MARK                          111111118 CFTT        130913   101100023424";
String extractAccountaccountNumber = record.substring(79, 87);
String newAccountNumber = "some value"
record = record.replaceFirst(extractAccountaccountNumber,newAccountNumber);
```

This may not work if there are duplicate values. Please advice

Comment: `record = record.substring(0, 79) + newAccountNumber + record.substring(87);` doesn't work?

Comment: I wrote a class which has fields with setter getter methods for all the fixed length values. It has two methods, populateFromString(String recordStr) and getRecordsString(); Once I populate the object, then i can replace the values and get the string back. It can be reused as well.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to assign it to a new String variable, or to itself:

```
string = string.replace("to", "xyz");
```

or

```
String newString = string.replace("to", "xyz");


public class Run1 {

public static final int its = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String record ="ABCU0MARK                          111111118 CFTT        130913          101100023424";

    String extractAccountaccountNumber = record.substring(46, 55);
    System.out.println("extractAccountaccountNumber:"+extractAccountaccountNumber);
    String newAccountNumber = "some value";
    String result=record.replaceFirst(extractAccountaccountNumber,newAccountNumber);
    System.out.println("result:"+result);

}
}
```

**here is result:**

extractAccountaccountNumber:FTT
result:ABCU0MARK                          111111118 Csome value  130913          101100023424

Comment: Your suggestion won't work, because I would end up replacing multiple places if the "to" is at other places too and it is highly possible the numbers would be duplicate in the string.

Comment: mmc18: I have the same piece of code, what you have wrote. Only my concern is, if the same set of number exists in the string at any other fixed length position, say before the position which I want to replace, it wouldn't work.It would end up replacing wrong place.

Comment: may be it could be about length of record